# GO concatenate string with int

Tags: go

I’ve the following code which needs to get int value and add it to a string with string suffix. E.g.

At start I'm getting this

```
"fds data "
```

After the `if` statement it should like this

```
"fds data 10 M"
```

This is the code:

```
ltrCfg := "fds data "
if len(cfg.ltrSharedDicts) > 0 {
    ltrCfg += strconv.Itoa(cfg.ltrSharedDicts["c_data"])
    ltrCfg += "M"
} else {
    ltrCfg += "10M"
}
out = append(out, ltrCfg)

ltrCert := “fds data "
if len(cfg.ltrSharedDicts) > 0 {
    ltrCert += strconv.Itoa(cfg.ltrSharedDicts["d_data"])
    ltrCert += "M"
} else {
    ltrCert += “20M"
}
out = append(out, ltrCert)
```

The code is working but I wonder for the first fork of the if statement

```
if len(cfg.ltrSharedDicts) > 0 {
    ltrCfg += strconv.Itoa(cfg.ltrSharedDicts["c_data"])
    ltrCfg += "M"
```

Is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: fmt.Sprintf will be much simpler, no?

Comment: I'd use fmt.Sprintf to do this kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability, I would write:

```
cd, ok := cfg.ltrSharedDicts["c_data"]
if !ok {
    cd = 10
}
out = append(out, fmt.Sprintf("fds data %dM", cd))
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I didnt understand the if ? sometimes it should get hardcoded value, you can see that on the `else`..

Comment: @NinaS: If the map doesn't contain a value for `"c_data"` (`!ok`) then use the default value (`10`). "The value of ok is true if the key x is present in the map, and false otherwise.": https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions